# Proving a theorem about covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, statistics, covariance

I wonder if the following proposition is true :

$X$ a random vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $E(||X||)<+\infty$,

if $det(D_{X})=0$

then $\exists \lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, such as $\displaystyle { \sum_{i=1}^{n}}\lambda_{i}(X_{i} - E(X_{i})) = 0$

with $D_{X}$ the covariance matrix of $X$

Thanks.

Comment: Guessing - $D_X$ will be singular if and only if two of the components of $X$ are completely correlated. Assuming, wlog, that they are $X_1$ and $X_2$ (and $\rho = (X_2-E(X_2))/(X_1-E(X_1)$), the values of $\lambda_1 = \rho$, $\lambda_2 = -1$, $\lambda_i=0, \forall i>2$ should do, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

If you denote by $\bar X_i = X_i - E(X_i) \cdot 1$ then the covariance
matrix is 
$$D_X= (\text{cov}(X_i, X_j))= (E(\bar X_i,\bar X_j))$$

Therefore $D_X$ is the Gram matrix associated to the elements $\bar X_i$. It is known that the Gram matrix associated to a family of vectors in a Hilbert space has zero determinant if and only if the vectors are linearly dependent. Therefore
$$\det D_X = 0 \Leftrightarrow \text{ there exist } \lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_n \text{ scalars so that }\\
\sum \lambda_i( X_i - E(X_i) ) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \\
\text{ there exist } \lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_n \text{ scalars so that }\\
\sum \lambda_i  X_i = \text{ constant} $$

Therefore the covariance matrix of $X$ has zero determinant if and only there exists a hyperplane that contains  the values of $X$ with probability $1$.

Note that for the existence of the matrix $D_X$ you also need $M_2(||X||)<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! One more thing, the scalar product associated with the gram matrix here is : $\langle u , v \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x)v(x)dx $ because of the expected value definition, right ?

Comment: The scalar product is better understood on the subspace of random variables with mean zero. So $\langle \bar X, \bar Y \rangle = E ( \bar X \cdot \bar Y) = E((X-E(X)) \cdot (Y - E(Y) ))$

Comment: I also found useful the formula $\det D_X= \det ( E(X_i \cdot X_j) )_{0\le i,j \le n}$, an $n+1$ dimensional determinant formed with the extra random variable $X_0\colon =1$. Note that the expectations are of the original variables, not the bar ones. This can give an alternate proof, indeed the condition is $\sum_{0\le i \le n} \alpha_i X_i = 0$ with $X_0 = 1$ constant.

Comment: Right ! So correct me if I'm wrong : the covariance isn't a scalar product in the general case, but with random variables with mean zero you can indeed verify the "definite" propriety which gives you a scalar product. 
In addition, your alternate proof is actually very quick and elegant, thanks for that.

Comment: Right, it is not. But it is obtained from a scalar product. To get the covariance of $X$, $Y$ you project them onto the subspace of random variables with mean zero $X\mapsto \bar X = X- E(X)$ and $Y\mapsto \bar Y$ and then $\text{cov}(X,Y) = E(\bar X\cdot \bar Y) = \langle \bar X, \bar Y \rangle$